# Why I can't create COM object in .NET but can in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, .net, com, activex

I can create an ActiveX in JS (html is opend by IE):

```
var o = new ActiveXObject("MyProgId");
```

But I can't create its instance in .NET:

```
var t = Type.GetTypeFromProgId("MyProgId");
```

returns null. When I try to add "reference to COM" in VS I get such error:

```
"Could not add a reference to {MyTypeLib_CLSID}\1.0
Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))"
```

When I search the registry for `MyTypeLib_CLSID` I do find the key but regedit can't open it under `HKCR\Wow6432Node\TypeLib`. It complains `Error Opening Key, The system cannot find the file specified`. But then I search next and regedit finds it under `HKCU\Software\Classes\TypeLib` and opens successfully there.

I also tried to create an object via `Type.GetTypeFromCLSID` with the same result (returns null).

What can be wrong with this COM?

P.S. This COM is Lync Web App Plugin ("ReachAppShAx.AppSharing"/{B89F72B4-7801-4F45-97AE-F9A0CDBB6213})

UPDATE: all these things happen locally: js/html is being opened in browser as a html-file, .net is a console app.

Comment: Is the ActiveX object you are trying to instantiate installed on **the server** which is where the ASP.NET code executes?

Comment: *"But I can't create its instance in .NET:"* Can you clarify that? Where/how are you running that .Net code? As Darin points out, if you're using ASP.Net, the .Net part of that runs *on the server*, whereas you seem to be using JavaScript in IE on the client for the other part.

Comment: No no, it's all local. Html with JS in browser is being opened locally (as a html-file). .NET program is a console app.

Comment: check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple to achieve this task using Visual Studio. (Instructions are for Visual Studio 2005)

1. Open a toolbox (View -> ToolBox)
2. Right-click on the toolbox -> Choose Items
3. Choose "COM Components" tab.
4. Select COM components of your interest.

References are added to the project automatically as well.

Now you can simply drag'n'drop your COM components since CCW (COM Callable Wrapper) should be created automatically by Visual Studio.

Comment: You can [mark that list up](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) as an actual list

Comment: @T.J. Crowder  - actually images are blocked in my company so can not able to see the images that formate the things

Comment: That list doesn't contains my COM object. What is point in trying to add COM components via Toolbox? I wrote in my question that I can't add reference to the COM dll.

Comment: @Pranay: No images involved, you can just do it as markdown. See the link I provided for details.

Comment: @Shrike -- check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It seems I understand why I can't create CCW in .net for this COM - it's because this COM is out-of-process COM server. So JavaScript/IE can work with out-of-process COMs seamlessly but not C#.

So the question turns to "How to deal with Out-of-process COM in .NET/C#".

I've created wrapper with help of tlbimp.exe: tlbimp.exe CommunicatorWebAppVersion.exe

This creates me dll CwaAsVersionLib.dll which I add into my C# project. And then create instance as:

```
var o = new CwaAsVersionLib.CwaAsVersionQuery();
```

But! It works only if COM server is running. If it's running then creating instance fails with error:
Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).